# create a table with a global secondary index error

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to create a table with a global secondary index using the javascript SDK inside of nodejs:

```
var messagesTableParams = {
    TableName : "Messages",
    KeySchema: [
        { AttributeName: "to", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
        { AttributeName: "tm", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        { AttributeName: "to", AttributeType: "N" },
        { AttributeName: "tm", AttributeType: "N" }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
        ReadCapacityUnits: 10,
        WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    },
    GlobalSecondaryIndexes: [
        {
            IndexName: 'fr_indx',
            KeySchema: [
                { AttributeName: "fr", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
                { AttributeName: "tm", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
            ],
            AttributeDefinitions: [
                { AttributeName: "fr", AttributeType: "N" },
                { AttributeName: "tm", AttributeType: "N" }
            ],
            Projection: {
                ProjectionType: 'KEYS_ONLY'
            },
            ProvisionedThroughput: {
                ReadCapacityUnits: 10,
                WriteCapacityUnits: 10
            }
        }
    ]
};

dynamodb.createTable(messagesTableParams, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to create table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Created table. Table description JSON:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

But I keep getting the following error and the table is not created:

> Unable to create table. Error JSON: {   "message": "Unexpected key
>   'AttributeDefinitions' found in params.GlobalSecondaryIndexes[0]",
>   "code": "UnexpectedParameter",   "time": "2016-01-07T18:51:11.659Z" }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have finally figured it out! I need to remove the AttributeDefinitions from the global index and then add a new entry for the 'fr' attribute into the table's AttributeDefinition!

I would like to thank all the people who have supported me through this tough time and tolerated my inexcusable language towards my computer!

Comment: So i totally under this answer is old, by any chance would you be able to update the answer with an example of the solution. I've done what you stated but i'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

For extra clarity here is the fixed code example

```
var messagesTableParams = {
  TableName: "Messages",
  KeySchema: [
    { AttributeName: "to", KeyType: "HASH" }, //Partition key
    { AttributeName: "tm", KeyType: "RANGE" }, //Sort key
  ],
  AttributeDefinitions: [
    { AttributeName: "to", AttributeType: "N" },
    { AttributeName: "tm", AttributeType: "N" },
    { AttributeName: "fr", AttributeType: "N" },
    { AttributeName: "tm", AttributeType: "N" },
  ],
  ProvisionedThroughput: {
    ReadCapacityUnits: 10,
    WriteCapacityUnits: 10,
  },
  GlobalSecondaryIndexes: [
    {
      IndexName: "fr_indx",
      KeySchema: [
        { AttributeName: "fr", KeyType: "HASH" }, //Partition key
        { AttributeName: "tm", KeyType: "RANGE" }, //Sort key
      ],
      Projection: {
        ProjectionType: "KEYS_ONLY",
      },
      ProvisionedThroughput: {
        ReadCapacityUnits: 10,
        WriteCapacityUnits: 10,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```